# how to show vector layers from shp in geoserver fast

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

i have so many columns in my shp,
i use data from my shp to show vector layer,
and i did it but sometimes take a long time even unresponsive script
can anyone help me how to show vector layers from shp in geoserver faster

this is my code that im using

```
var hitungJumlah = vectorSource.getFeatures();
for(var k=0;k<hitungJumlah.length;k++){
  var id = vectorSource.getFeatures()[k].getId();
  var feature = vectorSource.getFeatureById(id);
  if(feature.get('klas')!=null){
    var a = feature.get('klas');
  }else{
    a = "";
  }
  if(a=="Utama"){
    //warna is my ol.layer.Vector
    warna.getSource().addFeature(feature);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `vectorSource` as an intermediate source? Do you use it for something else? How do you load the features into `vectorSource`? How many features are there?

Comment: use a wms layer when zoomed out?